macOS 15.1 MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() returns false always
In my Catalyst app I use
  composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
  
  if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    if let vc = UIApplication.shared.presentedViewController {

      composer.mailComposeDelegate = self
      composer.setToRecipients("some Email address")
      composer.setSubject("Subject")
      ...
      ...

    }
  }

Since I have updated to macOS 15.1 the canSendMail() function returns false although I have configured Apple Mail (like before in 15.0 where it worked flawlessly).
Is this a bug in macOS 15.1. ?
Can anybody replicate this ?

Can confirm. Submitted FB15693837 to Apple.
